# Prevent entering values not in combo

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I'm having an editable combo box and user can type anything there. That should only work as intellisense and user can find values easily. But still user can type something which is not in combo box values list and proceed submitting.
How can I prevent submitting values which are not in combo box.

Comment: Then why use an 'editable combo box' instead of a standard `<select>` element which allows you to select only items in the list?

Answer (score 0):

It's a kendoComboBox. I checked whether any item is selected like this.

```
var compListSelectedItem = $("#gpCompList").data("kendoComboBox").dataItem();
 if (typeof compListSelectedItem == 'undefined'){
        return false;
 }
```